# Buying a house that has a natural spring flowing through the basement out to a pond. What to do?

Tags: water, basement

My husband and I are looking to buy a house from the 1800's and there is a natural spring in the basement that is stone trenched (*open*) out to an attached pond in the yard.

The current owners put plexiglass over the trench inside (*We assume, because of moisture issues the open trench caused in the basement*).  The plexiglass does have a lot of condensation on it.

What are the concerns with a trench like this and it being covered?

Do you think the moisture is still of concern?

Should the plexiglass have vents in it Or is there enough venting with it flowing to an outside trench?

Also, are there concerns of little critters or snakes attracted to this space?

Any experience towards owning a house with an open spring is greatly appreciated!  we're not sure if this is a deal breaker.

Comment: Is possible to speak with the previous owners and ask them about any of your concerns.

Comment: Would check house for rot and mould, before anything else, by a professional home inspector.

Comment: Might give you a nice option for a ground source heatpump, depending on the spring flow-rate.

Comment: Are you sure it's condensation and not mist?   For condensation to occur, the plexiglass needs to be colder than the water and since it's a ground water, that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: If I were you I definitely would buy a good moisture meter, and as you're inspecting the home, poke it anywhere that shouldn't get wet to make sure it isn't.  And if you do end up buying the home, repeat this process periodically.  Since this house has a source of water intrusion most don't, it could also have moisture problems that most inspectors won't know to look for.  But since the house has been standing so long, those problems are probably not deal-breakers and can be mitigated as long as you know about them.

Answer (score 2):

Would not (in concept) be a deal-breaker for me. Specific case might vary with detailed examination.

If you want to go high-falutin' Frank Lloyd Wright's Fallingwater had a spring in the entryway as well as being built over a stream (can't do that in new construction...)

The one you are looking at probably served as basic refrigeration and drinking water supply when built - stick the milk cans in the trough of cool water.

Critter control would normally be (this era) by having stainless steel screen that the water flows out through, but critters don't come upstream through.

I would not "vent" the covering to the house - that would defeat the point of having the covering.

Answer (score 2):

My uncle had a house like this.  Big spring too, several hundred gallons a minute. My recollection was that it was an easily visible current 4 feet wide and 10 inches deep.

Being in a warm climate, it was uncovered.  About 20 feet of it was in the house.  He had a window that was framed only on 3 sides with the unframed side an inch below the water level.  Outside it ran through a series of trout ponds.  Now and then a trout would come inside.

In theory it could have allowed critters that swim well (beaver, muskrat, skunk, raccoon, rat) to come in.  Don't recall him mentioning that.  He wanted the path under the glass to be free of obstruction in case one of the grandkids fell into the stream.  Didn't want them pinned to a screen by the current.